# Sum over symbolic function with multiplicative scalar

Tags: matlab, sum, symbolic-math

Consider a scalar vector `c = (c1,...,cn)` of length `n` and a function `f(i,x)` where `i` is a running index.

I need to construct the function `c1*f(1,x)+...+cn*f(n,x)`. I tried to use `symsum` which gives me

```
symsum(f(i,x),i,1,n))=f(1,x)+...+f(n,x)
```

but I don't know how to attach the `c`'s. I could use vector multiplication, but then I need to construct a vector which contains as elements functions. How can I construct a vector of functions?

Answer (score 0):

For your specific problem I would suggest to just use the matlab function 'sum', by defining a function f2(i,x,c) with

```
f2(i,x,c) = c(i)*f(i,x);
```

with f(i,x) the function you have defined before. Then you could just define your weight vector c:

```
c=linspace(-1,1,10); % for instance
```

and do

```
sum(f2([1:10],x,c))
```

Hope it helps!